# How to get Role Claims in IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have users that're part of Roles which have Claims specified for them. I authenticate my users using IdentityServer (version 3 at the moment) with IncludeAllClaimsForUser set to true. I expected IdentityServer to automatically retrieve Role Claims but it doesn't.

Is there a way to make IdentityServer care about Role Claims or is customizing through ProfileServer is the only way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need user information you have to use userinfo endpoint or while making a request for token add the scope that is related to user claim.